# Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 7 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BETWEEN'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I Run This Query

```
SELECT number, id, clientid, hash, 
    CASE WHEN expirydate IS NULL THEN 
            date 
        ELSE expirydate 
    END as date, 
    CASE company WHEN '' THEN 
            (
                SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', firstname, lastname) 
                FROM tblcontacts 
                WHERE userid = tblclients.userid 
                and is_primary = 1
            ) 
        ELSE company END as company 

FROM "tblestimates" 
    LEFT JOIN tblclients ON tblclients.userid=tblestimates.clientid
WHERE status != 3 
AND status != 4 
AND CASE WHEN expirydate IS NULL THEN 
        (date BETWEEN '2021-06-27' AND '2021-08-08') 
    ELSE (expirydate BETWEEN '2021-06-27' AND '2021-08-08') 
    END
```

I Got this Error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BETWEEN'.

Comment: I also strongly recommend you get into the habit of formatting your text; your SQL is difficult to read due to lack of it.

Comment: As for the error, `CASE` is an **expression** not a statement, it returns a scalar value, not a boolean result. Really, however, you should not be using a `CASE` **expression** in the `WHERE`; stick to `AND `and `OR` logic.

Comment: Tip: `coalesce(expirydate, date) as date`.

Comment: Even if you get `CASE` to work you'll probably end up with a full table scan. This query can be replaced by the *far simpler* `expirydate BETWEEN '202106-27' AND '202108-08' OR ( expirydate is NULL and date BETWEEN '20210627' AND '20210808')` which can use indexes that cover `expirydate` and `date`

Comment: You've tagged [[tag:sql-server2008]] here, but you use `CONCAT_WS`. That was introduced in SQL Server 2017; the above will fail due to the use of it. Are you *really* using the **completely** unsupported version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `case` in `where` clauses. That is unusual and unneccessary

```
AND 
(
      (expirydate IS NULL AND [date] BETWEEN '2021-06-27' AND '2021-08-08')
   OR expirydate BETWEEN '2021-06-27' AND '2021-08-08'
)
```

BTW `between` [is problematic](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common). Better use (note my date changes to `2021-08-09`)

```
AND 
(
      (expirydate IS NULL AND [date] >= '2021-06-27' AND [date] < '2021-08-09')
   OR expirydate >= '2021-06-27' AND expirydate < '2021-08-09'
)
```

Comment: `expirydate IS NOT NULL` isn't needed, because `BETWEEN` will fail if the value is NULL. I'm pretty certain the optimizer will eliminate this

Comment: In case it's not obvious to the OP, the entire clause should be bracketed to include it in the query.

Answer (score 0):

A CASE statement always resolves to some result value, so logically this would evaluate to either "true" or "false":

```
CASE
    WHEN expirydate IS NULL THEN 
        (date BETWEEN '2021-06-27' AND '2021-08-08') 
    ELSE
        (expirydate BETWEEN '2021-06-27' AND '2021-08-08') 
END
```

Unfortunately, SQL Server doesn't have a boolean data type, so you can't use the result of a comparison directly as an expression. Instead, you need to make the CASE statement return a supported type, like a BIT:

```
CASE 
    WHEN expirydate IS NULL AND date BETWEEN '2021-06-27' AND '2021-08-08'
        THEN 1
    WHEN expirydate IS NOT NULL AND expirydate BETWEEN '2021-06-27' AND '2021-08-08'
        THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END
```

You can then compare that result to make an expression in your WHERE clause:

```
WHERE 1 =
    CASE 
        WHEN expirydate IS NULL AND date BETWEEN '2021-06-27' AND '2021-08-08'
            THEN 1
        WHEN expirydate IS NOT NULL AND expirydate BETWEEN '2021-06-27' AND '2021-08-08'
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END
```

However, that combination can more naturally (and possibly more efficiently) be written with an OR, remembering to put it in brackets if combining it with AND:

```
WHERE 
  (
     expirydate IS NULL AND date BETWEEN '2021-06-27' AND '2021-08-08'
     OR
     expirydate IS NOT NULL AND expirydate BETWEEN '2021-06-27' AND '2021-08-08'
  )
```

In this particular case, you can write it even more simply with a COALESCE, because you're comparing whichever column is not null:

```
WHERE
    COALESCE(expirydate, date) BETWEEN '2021-06-27' AND '2021-08-08'
```

Comment: That's not a good idea. This will prevent the use of indexes

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Updated with a few variations. I think it's useful to understand the error and the most direct equivalent before moving onto wider changes.